# BingMap get polygons in view

Tags: javascript, bing-maps, polygons

I have map with 30-50 polygons on it. There are like 4000 points in every polygon but they are hidden at beginning. I want to disply the point only when zoom is <=6 but not all of the point but only ones related to the currently displayed polygon(s). So I need to get the polygons in view (displayed in this moment on the screen).
Do you know how to get the polys in view ?
ps.Im working with javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wont be quick if you have complex or lots of polygons but works (assumes v7 api):

https://gist.github.com/1704172

Comment: I've try this but returns error: Uncaught TypeError: Object [EntityCollection] has no method 'getLocations'

Comment: You tried my code on its own or integrated it into yours? Are you using Bing maps 7? Do you have pushpins as well and if so have U pit the polygons in a seperate entitycollection?

Comment: --- I have integrate it in mine ---- yes I'm using Bing maps 7 --- yes I have pushpins and they are on separate entitycollection

Comment: sorry last question, have you changed the code to only loop through the entity collection containing your polygons? It sounds like the loop is trying to call getLocations on an entity that is not a polygon (a pushpin for example doesnt have the getLocations method). If its not that can you share some code?

Comment: I think that it is possible that there was another entity that wasn't polygon... I can't test it now, because I have change the code of the whole project BUT your answer is looking good and useful so +100